Select status with if-else condition in SQL
Currently working on Snowflake. I want to write a SQL query for the following table:



pipeline
status




MONTHROPE
NoDelta


MONTHROPE
NoDataFound


MONTHROPE
NoFiles


DAYROPE
NoDataFound


FIVEROPE
NoDelta


DAYROPE
Failed


FIVEROPE
NoDelta


ANNUAL
NoDataFound



Requirement is to select one pipeline (after grouping) with a status of certain priority.
i.e. if NoDelta is present then it should be selected as it is first priority. else-if NoDataFound is  second priority.
Priority for select is NoDelta, NoDataFound, NoFiles, Failed.
Hence, the result should be as follows:



pipeline
status




MONTHROPE
NoDelta


DAYROPE
NoDataFound


FIVEROPE
NoDelta


ANNUAL
NoDataFound



Can you please help me form the query? I am trying to use CASE, but do not know the correct order.

Yes, those are the only ones. How do I rank? ORDER BY? Note that they are not asc or desc.

Which dbms are you using? (Don't waste other users' time writing answers that don't work on your dbms.)

Mentioned that currently working on Snowflake. I'll add a tag.

CASE assigns priority and QUALIFY selects the status with the highest priority for each pipeline.
SELECT
    pipeline,
    status
FROM table
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY pipeline
    ORDER BY CASE status
        WHEN 'NoDelta' THEN 1
        WHEN 'NoDataFound' THEN 2
        WHEN 'NoFiles' THEN 3
        WHEN 'Failed' THEN 4
        ELSE 5
    END ASC
) = 1
ORDER BY pipeline;


QUALIFY is a non-standard feature, supported only by a few. And the dbms is unknown here...

And that's a case expression, not statement.

@jarlh - It was mentioned at the start of the question "Currently working on Snowflake. I".
QUALIFY: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify

I see, I saw the one and only tag , which means general ANSI/ISO SQL.

Thanks @keithwalsh. I'll add tag for snowflake
